# Intellij Idea: Method breakpoints may dramatically slow down debugging

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Иногда начал получать такую ошибку в Intellij. В связи с этим установка приложения становится крайне медленной. Может кто объяснить чем вызвана эта ошибка и что можно сделать, чтоб ее избежать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо понимать разницу между [типами](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#breakpoint-types) точек останова - в IDEA их четыре:

- остановка на определенной строке кода
- остановка при входе в определенный метод (или возврате из него)
- остановка при обращении к определенной переменной
- остановка при возникновении исключения

Предупреждение связано только со вторым типом, и использовать его следует только при крайней необходимости.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Выключите точки остановки (breakpoints) метода. Вы можете увидеть все свои точки остановки через Debug -> View Breakpoints (Ctrl + Shift + F8)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятно почему это происходит и как это можно зафиксить кроме удаления точек